# Get element's inherited (cascaded) ancestor CSS classes using Javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, css, parent, ancestor

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.className + "->" + e.target.parentNode.className);
        });
    }
};
```

```css
.outer_box_green{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:green;
}
.inner_box_thick{
  margin:2px;
  padding:3px;
  border-style:dashed;
  border-width:4px;

}
.line_1{
  font-size:2em;
  display:block;
}
.line_2{
  font-size:4em;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="outer_box_green">
      <div class="inner_box_thick another_inner_box_class">
        <span class="line_1">Line 1</span>
        <span class="line_2">Line 2</span>
        <div>Line 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Using vanilla Javascript, how can we get the classes of a clicked element and all the classes of the "ancestor" elements the clicked element is nested within.  For example, if we have

```
<div class="outer_box_green">
  <div class="inner_box_thick another_inner_box_class">
    <span class="line_1">Line 1</span>
    <span class="line_2">Line 2</span>
    <div>Line 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The desired behavior is to get Javascript arrays containing ancestors' classes when an element is clicked:

- "Line 1" is clicked

  - `["line_1", "inner_box_thick", "another_inner_box_class", "outer_box_green"]`
- "Line 2" is clicked

  - `["line_2", "inner_box_thick", "another_inner_box_class", "outer_box_green"]`
- "Line 3" is clicked

  - `["inner_box_thick", "another_inner_box_class", "outer_box_green"]`

I figured out how to print the classes using `parentNode.className` but it only goes up one level (see snippet).  How can this be done to get all CSS classes of all nested HTML ancestors at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move up the DOM tree until the `parentNode` becomes `null`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      const classNames = [];
      let node = e.target;
      while(node != null){
        if(node.className) classNames.push(node.className);
        node = node.parentNode;
      }
      console.log(...classNames);
    });
  }
};
```

```css
.outer_box_green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

.inner_box_thick {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 4px;
}

.line_1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: block;
}

.line_2 {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_box_green">
  <div class="inner_box_thick another_inner_box_class">
    <span class="line_1">Line 1</span>
    <span class="line_2">Line 2</span>
    <div>Line 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```